# Merging Duplicate entries in a C# List

Tags: c#

I have a List in C#, of a custom class:

```
     public class Pose
        {
    
            public int Label { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public double Value { get; set; }   
        }

List<Pose> poses = new List<Pose>();
```

The list is populated, and contains entries with duplicate Name values.

What I would like to do is average the `Value` entry of the duplicate `Name` elements in the List.

If my List is currently:

```
Pose(0,"one",1);
Pose(1,"two",4);
Pose(2,"one",2);
Pose(3,"two",5);
Pose(4,"one",6);
Pose(5,"two",3);
```

i would like to end up with:

```
Pose(0,"one",3.333); //average of the 'one' values
Pose(1,"two",4);//average of the 'two' values
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can use Linq, GroupBy then average

Comment: Not a complete duplicate. Missing auto-incremented `Label` property in the resulting list.

Comment: @Dialecticus, thanks! How can I keep the 'Label' property in the above example?

Comment: You want to keep it? I guess you can use `Min` on `Label` (just as you use `Average` on `Value`). I previously assumed you don't want to keep the numbering, but renumber them anew.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, i need to renumber them anew! What is the approach for this?

Comment: @anti, there are two overloads of `Select` method. One of them provides you with the index of the current element, `.Select((x, index) => new Pose() { Label = index, Name = x.Key, value = x.Average() })`.